# How can I format a statement and a loop in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I've created a looping statement which prints out a sentence based on a specific condition:

```
`for key in dict:
    print(key)
  if dict[key] > 500:
    print('This costs more than 500' )
  else:
    print('This costs less than 500.')`
```

I'd like for the keys to print side by side to the statement.

Comment: what do you mean by printing odd ? also this is doing same iterating through each key and checking condition,

Comment: Are you asking how to turn this loop into a function? Your question is unclear.

Comment: *"But it is printing quite odd"* - Please explain what you mean.  What *exactly* is the desired behavior, and what *exactly* does it currently do?  What you have looks correct based on your description.

Comment: I think this should work fine. Can you please show what result it is printing?

Comment: I was hoping to get the printed statements side by side, instead of next to each other. I realize my question was completely unclear, I apologize!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do your desired wor.
You can pass any dictinary as a parameter to this function

```
def cost_printing(dict):
    for key in dict:
        #print(key)
        if dict[key] > 500:
            print('value {} costs more than 500.'.format(dict[key]))
        else:
            print('value {} costs less than 500.'.format(dict[key]))

cost_printing(dict1)

cost_printing(dict2)
```